# Topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have created a topic in MSK(Kafka).
And also i have registered avro  schema .
Now i am trying to produce a message to the topic ,But when i run my producer i get below error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic AVRO-AUDIT_EVENT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Here is my java code to produce avro message

```
String topicName = "AVRO-AUDIT_EVENT";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers",
                "b-3.*****:9092,b-4.****:9092,b-5.****:9092");
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081/subjects/AVRO-AUDIT-EVENT/versions/");

        JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json);
        String bodyofJson = job.getString("body");
        JSONObject bodyJsonObj = new JSONObject(bodyofJson);
        System.out.println(bodyJsonObj.get("ID"));

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        try {

            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, bodyJsonObj.get("ID").toString(), bodyofJson))
                    .get();

            System.out.println("Complete");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            producer.close();
        }
```

I can list the topic and see the topic name as well and also i can read the topic message .But when i runt this i get this error .

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are not running Kafka locally...

Remove this line

```
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
```

Maybe deploy schema registry in AWS as well, and change this line (as well as the address)

```
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081/");
```

Also, if you want to send Avro, create a `GenericRecord` Avro object, not a JSON String. Otherwise, your schema is just `"string"`

Comment: sorry i did not get your point AVRO object ..How do i create it ..I am parsing json from amazon API input ..

Comment: Your code generates no Avro objects, at all. Remove all usages of `JSONObject` and please read https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-avro-course/blob/master/avro-examples/src/main/java/com/github/simplesteph/avro/generic/GenericRecordExamples.java#L18-L42

Comment: I did modified but now i am getting `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message` error .. So i is it matador to use schema and Generic avro ?

Comment: Also i have registered schema in `http://localhost:8081/subjects/AVRO-AUDIT-EVENT/versions/` so i have give this location right ?

Comment: 1) That is not the full error 2) The url in the code does not include anything after the port

Comment: Maybe it would help you if you followed a full video course walkthough https://www.udemy.com/course/confluent-schema-registry/

Comment: Thats a good idea ..I will finish this ...Thanks for sharing this

Answer (score 1):

In my case over the weekend it lost the connection to all the nodes. It seems that it doesn't recover the connection automatically.

After restarting the service, it worked just fine.